# Cups in strictly convex domain (peeling a potato)

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry

Suppose that $D$ is strictly convex domain in $\mathbb R^n$. By a cup we mean a connected component of $\bar D\setminus H$, where $H$ is a hyperplane.

The question is as follows: given $\epsilon>0$ and a compact subset $K$ of $D$ does there exist a finite number of pairwise disjoint cups $C_1,\ldots, C_m$ that do not intersect $K$ and such that $m(\partial D\setminus (C_1\cup\ldots \cup C_m))<\epsilon$?

We can answer this question (and the answer is not so complicated). However, it seems so natural, that it must be known. Does anyone know a reference for it?

I would also ask to what extent it can be generalized? We see the proof for strictly convex case (i.e. in analytic sense). What about strongly convex domains (or, in general, convex ones)?

Comment: Why do you need $\epsilon$? It seems that there exist caps not intersecting $K$ which cover the whole $\partial D$. And the domain does not have to be strictly convex. Just convex is enough.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. C_j must be pairwise disjoint. I added this assumption. Actually, this is trivial for n=2.

Comment: Is $D$ assumed to be bounded?

Comment: Yes, it is assumed to be bounded.